# Tag excerpts on MSE and MSO contains HTML paragraph tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki, popups

When hovering over the tag you can see that the excerpt is enclosed by paragraph tags (just hover over the tags on this question as a test).

[image]

Which kind of makes sense as if you look at the [tag info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) you can see it:

[image]

However, looking at the [tag excerpt history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250232/revisions), it's *not* there:

[image]

So where has the `<p>...</p>` come from all of a sudden?

**Note: this affects all tags in several sites, e.g. here on MSE and on Stack Overflow.**

Comment: Someone encoded something that shouldn't have been encoded

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure it does affect all tags across all sites. SF&F and CR for instance seem to be fine (their main and meta)...

Comment: Weird. Well, edited, just assumed that if it's both here and on SO, it affects all sites

Comment: something went wrong while rebaking posts, no need to fix manually, will rebake asap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bug in the post rebaking code. It didn't exclude tag wiki excerpts from the Markdown processing pipeline.

[image: I bake]

MSE and MSO and SO have already been fixed.

Comment: Any chance [this is another side effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286790/i-cant-subscribe-to-tag-on-ru-stackoverflow-com) of the bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope, this was https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/798290543809884162

Comment: Not sure I follow... how cleaning up insecure image URL's is related to tag subscription? Anyway, kudos for the huge cleanup! :)