# I can't subscribe to tag on ru.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stackexchange.com, subscription

For example, I signed up for "[битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81/info)" tag.
I received a confirmation email:

> You've chosen to receive email updates on new questions tagged "".

And my subscription was without a tag, ie all the questions the community.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was impossible to subscribe to any tag containing non-ASCII characters, not only for Russian. But it's fixed now:

[image]

Note however that you may need to create your subscription again to get it working.

Comment: Just curious, was it always broken, or did a recent change cause this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Originally there were no such thing as non-English sites, therefore there were no such thing as non-ASCII tags. Then "Stack Overflow in (language)" and "(language) Stack Exchange" sites were born, and tag processing code was modified to allow non-ASCII tags... but only in the codebase for the network sites, not in the one for stackexchange.com. So I guess the answer is "it was always broken".